# NSMutableDictionary of SKSpriteNode

Tags: objective-c, nsmutabledictionary

I am new to objective-C and I am having harsh time with its semantics. Let say I have a bunch of SKSpriteNode stored in a NSMutableDictionary pointing to an enum status for each sprite code:

```
typedef enum PAWN_STATUS { OUT=0, MOVING, LANDED, IDLE } PAWN_STATUS;
```

and then

```
NSMutableDictionary* pawns = [[NSMutableDictionary alloc] init];

for(int i=0; i<10; ++i) {
   SKSpriteNode *whiteButton = [SKSpriteNode spriteNodeWithImageNamed:@"white"];
   [pawns setObject:[NSNumber numberWithInt:OUT] forKey:whiteButton];
}
```

then I change the status for some sprite, say

```
SKSpriteNode *touchedNode = (SKSpriteNode *)[self nodeAtPoint:location];
[pawns setObject:[NSNumber numberWithInt:LANDED] forKey:touchedNode];
```

But instead of changing the status of an existing SKSpriteNode, the last line is ADDING a new SKSpriteNode. So my question is why this is so? The hash is not defined for Nodes?

Comment: Don't you have your key/value objects back-to-front when adding them to the dictionary?

Comment: Sorry trojanfoe but what do you mean by back-to-front?

Comment: where does `floatingPawnButton` come from? should it not be `touchedNode`?

Comment: You think keys are values and values are keys.  Surely your sprites are the objects and those numbers are the keys?

Comment: would you also add a `NSLog(@"pawns: %@", pawns);` at the end of the `for` to check that the dictionary is correctly populated? and NSLog of `floatingPawnButton` to hand-check if it is already there.

Comment: @sergio: yes it is touched node. I amend it. Also the dictionary is being correctly populated. I also test for the touched node of being of the created sprites. But when changing the status, a new object is added.

Comment: @trojanfoe non dude I am not confusing keys/values. My keys are the SKSpriteNode and my values an enum (Actually a NSNumber). I want a handy way of knowing the status of my sprites.

Comment: You are going down the wrong path.  You need to employ an MVC design pattern and each model object can hold a reference to the sprite object.  Also I doubt sprites make the best key objects for dictionaries (just guessing tho.).

Comment: @trojanfoe It's incredible that you are suggesting a design. I am not asking something about software architecture. I'd wrote enough software in my life for knowing when to apply patterns but I am new to Objective-C. Keep focus on the question, it is about dictionaries...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would suggest a completely different approach to what you are trying to accomplish.

You can indeed associate user data to your nodes by using the following `SKNode` property:

```
 @property(retain, nonatomic) NSMutableDictionary *userData
```

So, you do not need to handle your own dictionary associating a node to its status. You can just do:

```
 touchedNode.userData = @{@"myNodeState":@LANDED};
```

Later on, you would do:

```
if ([touchedNode.userData[@"myNodeState"] intValue] == LANDED)
    ...
```

Notice also the use of "modern" Objective-C syntax making it easier.

Another unrelated improvement to readability would come from using `static const * NSString` instead of enums for your state:

In .h file:

```
typedef NSString* MyStateEnums;
const MyStateEnums MyStateEnumLanded;
```

In .m file:

```
const MyStateEnums kMyStateEnumLanded = @"landedNodeState";
```

So you can just do:

```
     touchedNode.userData = @{@"myNodeState": kMyStateEnumLanded};
```

and more importantly:

```
if (touchedNode.userData[@"myNodeState"] == kMyStateEnumLanded)
```

EDIT:

in order to check if NSDictionary works with SKNodeSprite, do this simple test:

```
//-- your code:
NSMutableDictionary* pawns = [[NSMutableDictionary alloc] init];
for(int i=0; i<10; ++i) {
   SKSpriteNode *whiteButton = [SKSpriteNode spriteNodeWithImageNamed:@"white"];
   [pawns setObject:[NSNumber numberWithInt:OUT] forKey:whiteButton];
}
//-- testing:
for (SKSpriteNode* node in [pawns allKeys]) {
    [pawns setObject:[NSNumber numberWithInt:LANDED] forKey:node];
}
for (SKSpriteNode* node in [pawns allKeys]) {
    NSLog(@"Node %x state: %d", (int)node, [[pawns objectForKey:node] intValue]);
}
```

Comment: Sure sergio I know I can do that, thanks. But this does not solves the question why NSMutableDictionary is adding a new object instead of modifying the existing one? Is it because SKSpriteNode is not defining hash values?

Comment: I believe the issue lies in the lack of an MVC pattern in the OPs code (where part of the view is a sprite in this case).  Just modelling the "state" of an entity (which is represented on the screen using a sprite) is the tip-of-the-iceberg and other attributes will need modelling.

Comment: @JuanChô: unfortunately, I haven't got all of your code at my disposal to check where the problem lies. I suggest you make the simple test I added to my answer and report on its outcome.

Comment: @sergio The code you'd provided is churning out Node 9c68ea0 state: 2 (node value is changing of course) but the value is changing correctly. BUT you are iterating through the keys.

Comment: there is no difference between iterating through the keys using `objectForKey:` and using `objectForKey:` with a given value (or `setObject:forKey:`). the only difference is that in the first case I am **sure** that the object is in the dictionary -- in the second I am not and the object might not be in the dictionary -- which seems to be your case, so it is added (expectedly).

Comment: You do not show what you do with your nodes after the `for` loop -- do you add them to the scene? to some parent node? possibly there lies the issue root cause… are you addend the very same nodes that you tap on? please show some more code...

Comment: mmm, I understant what you mean. Look, the addresses showed by the NSLog for all the sprites ARE Different from the ONE which is touched. I mean touchedNode memory address does not belong to the Dictionary. This explains why a new member is being added. But this raises another question. Why when I select the sprite, the address changes? It is because the parent? I am adding the sprite to the current parent.

Comment: @sergio, so do you think the parent is, say, creating its own copy of the sprites? This can explain why addresses are different.

Comment: @JuanChô: that might explain it, for sure. if you are sure you do not add any more nodes than this in the `for` loop than a safe assumption is the nodes are copied.

Comment: It is certainly copying. Well this is annoying. I am going to use your suggestion. Many thanks sergio.